# How to fetch a column in non sql database

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am unable to fetch a column in non sql database. I am working on google app engine. I have googled it but could not find the answer.

```
availability_from = cls.query(cls.From == From).order(-cls.From).fetch()
```

Comment: What's the expected result from this code? and what's the error message say?

Comment: I  am expecting to fetch a particular column (whose attribute is From) but i am getting whole database.

Comment: Well, you're not telling it to fetch one column, you're instructing it to fetch every row where `Form == Form`, it's like saying `WHERE 1==1`..?

Comment: yes. but i want to fetch one column......thanks Torex..I have got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch whole database into a list(a) then take out the required column of database

```
a = cls.query().fetch()
b = list(a)
j = []
k = 0
for p in b:
    j.append(p.From)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
availability_from = cls.query(cls.From == From).order(-cls.From).fetch()
```

Will give you object, suppose you have a column name 'user_name' to get the value for user_name column you need to use

```
availability_from.user_name
```

If you are looking for a query which only fetch selective column/s they you need to make index and use [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries)